# Redirect User to custom URL after registering

Tags: plugin-development, user-registration

I modified the default Wordpress registration page to include a role and also payment fields. I am adding a Gold Member feature the my website, which requires payment.

I'd like it that after this user makes a payment and it is approved, he gets redirected back to the home page. I'm using the registration_errors filter to achieve this.  This is not working, the user is instead redirected back to the wp-login page with a successful message on top.

Additionally, the wp_update_user function is not working either; the user is added to the db with the default role - Subscriber. How do I pass the user_id in here? Or, should I do this in another place.

```
function process_payment($errors, $sanitized_user_login, $user_email) {

if ( $errors->get_error_code() ) return $errors;

global $tran;

if($tran->Process()) {
    $approved = $tran->authcode;
    add_filter('registration_redirect', 'gold_login_redirect');
            wp_update_user( array ('ID' => $user_id, 'role' => 'gold_member') ) ;

} else {
    $errors->add( 'fidelipay_response', __('<strong>Declined</strong>:'. $tran->result . '<br/>' . $tran->error . '<br/>' . $tran->cvv2_result . '<br/>' ,'mysite.com') );
        if($tran->curlerror) {
            $errors->add( 'fidelipay_response', __('<strong>Reason</strong>:' . $tran->curlerror, 'mysite.com'));   
            return $errors; 
        }
        return $errors;                                                         
}
  return $errors;
}

add_filter('registration_errors', 'process_payment', 10, 3);

function gold_login_redirect() {
     return home_url('?role=gold_member');
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `wp_redirect` function ([Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_redirect)) at any point where you want to redirect the user:

```
wp_redirect( home_url() ); exit;
```

Comment: Thanks, the redirection worked, but the user didn't get entered into the db.

Comment: @MF1 here's what [the doc](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_update_user) says: `To create a new user, use wp_insert_user() instead.`